How to go to production with Symfony 6.4
I tried following online guides but I can't get Symfony 6.4 to work in production.
I tried giving permissions to the var/ folder, changing APP_ENV=prod and APP_DEBUG=0 in the .env, but it doesn't work.
I also tried to install the packages with the --no-dev --optimize-autoloader flag via composer.
In my project I use Stimulus controller and Leaflet.
As soon as I do these operations, Symfony stops running.

What does symfony check:requirements say

[OK]
Your system is ready to run Symfony projects

Can you share some details on the issue/errors you are receiving ? Also have you put the path properly in the "webpack.config.js" file present in the roots and other location where you are loading the files ?
